# generate scale free network with power-law degree distribution by python

Tags: python, networkx, power-law

I write this code to generate scale free network with power law degree distribution.

```
import networkx as nx
import random
N = 1000
exponent = 2.2
test = [int(random.paretovariate(exponent-1)) for i in range(N)]
graph = nx.configuration_model(test)
print("number of self-loops : ",  graph.number_of_selfloops())
```

but I face this error:

> AttributeError: 'MultiGraph' object has no attribute 'number_of_selfloops'

I can't understand what is the problem and how can I fix it.
Is there any other ways to generate such network with networkX? (I don't want self-loops and multi-links to be removed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the documentation of [`configuration_model`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.generators.degree_seq.configuration_model.html) this function returns a `MultiGraph`, which does not have the method `number_of_selfloops`, but you can still use the `nx.number_of_selfloops` method, which also works for `MultiGraph` (NetworkX changed how they want to have the call for such methods) or simply create a usual graph with `non_multi_graph = nx.Graph(graph)`.

Comment: I want to have MultiGraph. I don't want to remove multi-links and self-loops. This code  : non_multi_graph = nx.Graph(graph)  return Graph and also I get this error again : 'Graph' object has no attribute 'number_of_selfloops' @Sparky05