# Generate a power-law degree distribution in python

Tags: python, graph, statistics, networkx

Let `n` be the size of the network, and `t` be the power-law exponent. The goal is to generate a random graph `G` of `n` vertices with a power-law degree distribution specified by `t`.

There are several existing answers: (1) [answer 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61131416/generate-scale-free-network-with-power-law-degree-distribution-by-python) and (2) [answer 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28920824/generate-a-scale-free-network-with-a-power-law-degree-distributions), which all use `random.paretovariate()` function. However, this is no guarantee that the resulting sequence is a valid degree sequence.

I also checked networkx and failed to find any function that produces a power-law degree sequence. Is there a way to do this in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `networkx`. The `is_graphical` function allows you to determine whether the results of the `powerlaw_sequence` function are a valid degree sequence. Once we generate a valid sequence, we can create a random graph from it.

```
    from networkx.generators.degree_seq import random_degree_sequence_graph
    from networkx.algorithms.graphical import is_graphical
    from networkx.utils.random_sequence import powerlaw_sequence
    
    
    n, t = 10, 2
    while True:  # Continue generating sequences until one of them is graphical
        seq = sorted([int(round(d)) for d in powerlaw_sequence(n, t)], reverse=True)  # Round to nearest integer to obtain DISCRETE degree sequence
        if is_graphical(seq):
            break
    G = random_degree_sequence_graph(seq, tries=100)  # Adjust number of tries as you see fit
    print(sorted(d for _, d in G.degree()))
```